# asp mvc reporting services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, reporting-services

How to insert a report I already prepared into a view? I'm working on a .net mvc web application. What code shoud I add to the .cshtml file?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  It is not clear from your question what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: What is your reporting tool? Is it reporting services that is used in web forms?

Comment: Recently seen on SQL Server Reporting Services Team: Microsoft acquires report rendering technology from Forerunner Software - Not ready yet and not a schedule, but at least good to know they are working on something. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2018/04/02/microsoft-acquires-report-rendering-technology-from-forerunner-software/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a ReportView to your cshtml to create reports, that's because it's a component for web forms. The most that you can do, it's add a folder in your mvc project and Create a Web Form to this folder, and add the report Viewer to this WebForm.